# How to get CSS to work only on specific WordPress pages?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've read a few forums but I must be missing something.  I'm basically just trying to have certain things in my CSS work for certain pages.  Basically I wanted to change the homepage to be full width for the pictures.

My CSS in my child theme was this.

```
.site-content,
.fl-builder.home .page-section,
.front-page-widgets,
.breadcrumbs {
    width: 1640px;
    max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-footer-area {
    width: 1640px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Problem is now on all my pages since the `max-width` is 100% everything is touching the edge of the screen.  I only wanted this for the home page.  I inspected the home page and from this

```
<body id="top" class="admin-bar home is-singular logged-in page page-id-481 page-template page-template-_fullwidth page-template-page-template page-template-page-template_fullwidth-php customize-support">
```

I'm assuming my `page-id` is 481 for the home page.

Whats the best method to fix this so the rest of my pages are normal?

Comment: Isn't the class `home` a better candidate?

Comment: Try adding a containing div with a class to every page you want changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .home or page-id-481 as parent

```
.home your_selector{
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.page-id-481 your_selector{
     max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I had to add it to each selector like @Tomek said but the .home didn't seem to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend **each** of your home-related css selectors with `.home`, e.g.:

```
.home .site-content,
.home .page-section,
.home .front-page-widgets,
.home .breadcrumbs {
    width: 1640px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So if you have a css rule added to several selectors listed one after the other, you have to add `.home` as many times.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your different template files in your wordpress theme, make one named `front-page.php` and set the width of this page to 100% while leaving your other theme files alone.

such as

```
<div class="home-width">
    My home page
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Wordpress automatically looks for certain named pages for different things and in the Customize menu you can still decide what you want your front page to be. It also gives you complete freedom to choose the layout of your homepage while keeping the rest organized as a blog or whatever else layout you want for the site.